# Mousemove on Geoserver Tile with Leaflet

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, mouse-position

Coming from intensive usage of Leaflet with open source tiles and remote data layers (multipolygons, markers, etc...) retrieved from a PostgreSql database, I wanted to try Geoserver capabilities to achieve - more or less - same capabilities (display polygons, managing hover and click events, display additional data etc...).

Till now, I achieved to display a polygons on a Leaflet map using TMS (perfs are so incredible to my point of view).

Next step was to implement the "mouseover"/"mouseout" event on polygons displayed from tiles, just to indicate to the user that he's mouse hovering a polygon.

So, I retrieve the tiles, then, I retrieve the bounding box of the layers to only listen on the `mousemove` Leaflet event in this particular area. 

For each captured event, I'm using the `GetFeatureInfo` request to retrieve the hovered polygon, then I add the polygon to the map with a different style.

**JavaScript code :**

```
let map;

function init() {
    map = new L.Map('map');

    // GeoServer tiles URL
    const tilesURL = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/adcf:epci_2018@EPSG:900913@jpeg/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg';
    const attr     = 'Map data © <a href="https://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';

    const tilesLayer = new L.TileLayer(tilesURL, {maxZoom: 18, attribution: attr, tms: true});

    map.setView(new L.LatLng(46.29381556233369, 2.3620605468750004), 6);
    map.addLayer(tilesLayer);

    // Reference to the polygon created from mousemove event
    let hovered = null;

    // Get tiles polygons bounding box to limit event triggering
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?request=GetCapabilities').then((res) => {
        res.text().then((xml) => {
            const capabilities = parser.parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml');
            const layers = capabilities.getElementsByTagName('Layer');

            for (const layer of layers) {
                for (const child of layer.children) {
                    if (child.tagName === 'Name' && child.innerHTML === 'adcf:epci_2018') {
                        const bbox = layer.querySelectorAll('BoundingBox[CRS="EPSG:4326"]')[0];

                        // Bouding box polygon
                        const bboxLayer = new L.polygon([
                            [bbox.getAttribute('minx'), bbox.getAttribute('miny')],
                            [bbox.getAttribute('minx'), bbox.getAttribute('maxy')],
                            [bbox.getAttribute('maxx'), bbox.getAttribute('maxy')],
                            [bbox.getAttribute('maxx'), bbox.getAttribute('miny')],
                        ], {color: 'red', fillOpacity: 0})
                        // When moving over the bbox polygon, call GetFeatureInfo request to retrieve hovered polygon
                        .on('mousemove', (e) => {
                            // Build GetFeeatureInfo request parameters
                            const target = map.latLngToContainerPoint(e.latlng, map.getZoom());
                            const size   = map.getSize();

                            const sw = map.getBounds().getSouthWest();
                            const ne = map.getBounds().getNorthEast();

                            const params = {
                                request: 'GetFeatureInfo',
                                query_layers: 'adcf:epci_2018',
                                layers: 'adcf:epci_2018',
                                x: Math.round(target.x),
                                y: Math.round(target.y),
                                height: size.y,
                                width: size.x,
                                info_format: 'application/json',
                                bbox: sw.lng + ',' + sw.lat + ',' + ne.lng + ',' + ne.lat,
                            };

                            // Call GetFeatureInfo request then add hovered polygon to the map
                            fetch('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms' + L.Util.getParamString(params)).then((res) => {
                                res.json().then((json) => {
                                    if (hovered !== null) {
                                        map.removeLayer(hovered);
                                    }
                                    if (json.features.length > 0) {
                                        hovered = L.geoJson(json).addTo(map);
                                    }
                                });
                            });

                        })
                        .addTo(map); 
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });

}

init();
```

**Screenshots (yellow dot is cursor) :**
[image: basemap : tiles and bbox (in red) retrieved]

Code works nearly fine, but there is a vertical gap between the cursor position, and the layer retrieved by `GetFeatureInfo` request. This vertical gap is increasing depending on the zoom level (zoom less, gap more). **From zoom >= level 7, it works almost precisely.**

[image: gap depending on zoom]

Well, I'm wondering what's wrong with code or maybe with Geoserver layers configuration. Because the problem is only on the vertical axis, and disappear when zooming.

Answer (score 3):

> there is a vertical gap between the cursor position, and the layer retrieved by GetFeatureInfo request.

No, probably what you really mean to say is "there is a latitude shift between the cursor position and the *latitude I'm using in the `getFeatureInfo` query*".

Leaflet uses EPSG:3857 for display (and for screen-relative coordinates; historically called EPSG:900913), and EPSG:4326 for the `latlng`s. However, your code is explicitly converting the `mouseover` coordinates into screen-relative coordinates, effectively performing a linear interpolation of the EPSG:4326 coordinates.

Rely on `e.latlng` for the coordinates of the point your pointer device is hovering over, or rely on something like https://github.com/heigeo/leaflet.wms for the `getFeatureInfo` queries.